# Convert Swing Application to 3tier application

Tags: java, mysql, swing

After one year i have finished the development of my application.
Now when searching the internet i got a new knowledge about the 3tiers applications.

My Application running on 2tier Architecture (Standalone application connecting directly to database server).

My Application Developed using:
- Java SE (Swing).
- MySQL Server as database server.

I want to reconstruct my application to be 3tier application. (Client-Server)
- What technology i have to use?
- What I have to change within my current code?
- The application will run on network, there will be Many concurrent users who will use the application accessing the database (Insert,Update,Delete ... etc).

Comment: swing is a standalone application.You can not make client server like we use jsp/servlet

Comment: You can develop SOFEA (Service Oriented Front End architecture) to convert your application into 3 tier Client server application. You develop you client in Swing and expose all business logic as service(REST/SOAP). In this approach you can reuse most of your code. You can use HTML and AJAX and develop browser based using the  application SOFEA.

Comment: jallinone.sourceforge.net/setup.html, this idea i found while searching. It's using swing. my application for ERP as this one, Just i need to set a middle tier between my thin client & MySQL server. using something like EJB without going to web

Comment: @AmeeraKhaleel you can go for javafx.This supports both standalone and web side.Also it has good look and feel than swing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main approaches. The first involves rewriting the client in HTML/JavaScript with help from one of the many available frameworks (Struts, Spring, Java Server Faces, etc.) Unless you specifically prefer a web application to a Swing application, or your user interface is a very thin layer on top of your business logic, then this is a costly approach.

The second approach involves inserting a server between your user interface and your database. Open source Java-based servers include Jetty, Tomcat, Spring, JBoss/WildFly and GlassFish.

If your code is structured in layers so that the user interface, the business logic and the data access code belong to separate layers, then converting from a two-tier system to a three-tier system should be straightforward once you understand the capabilities of your chosen mid-tier server and how to use them.

The basic technique is:

1. All user interface/Swing code remains on the client.
2. All business logic moves to the middle-tier server. The client talks to the business logic using a remote protocol.
3. All data access code is moved to the server.

Dependency Injection is useful to perform this refactoring step-by-step and also allow you to choose between working in two-tier or three-tier mode if that is needed.

The three main differences between a two-tier and three-tier application are:

1. Security - there is a new access point into your system. You need to be careful about the access rights it has to the database - do you have one server user that can do everything, or does each user need to use their own connection credentials. You also need to secure the server correctly and be careful not to add security holes in your mid-tier API.
2. Remote access - some method calls that were previously made within the same process are now made across the network. Server APIs generally need to support less fine-grained operations than local APIs, and the amount of data shipped as arguments and return values may also need to be managed.
3. The structure of your application becomes more important. The code isn't necessarily very different, but it will need to be organised into different layers.

Comment: This is the most acceptable answer for now, I have to move SQL Statements to the mid-tier, clients will connect to the mid-tier, med-tier connect to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is your answer.You could choose a framework like Hibernate/Spring/Struts to build a 3 tier architecture (MVC).You would also need to make a choice for a servlet container.Apache Tomcat should be a good choice.

It would be nice if you could post little more details like complexity , purpose etc. of your application.

Comment: http://jallinone.sourceforge.net/setup.html, this idea i found while searching. It's using swing. my application for ERP as this one, Just i need to set a middle tier between my thin client & MySQL server. using something like EJB without going to web

Comment: Ok. So I am guessing you do not intend to re engineer the application , but want to take the existing structure to a 3 tier architecture.So you could make use of web services. EJB would bring increase the complexity.

Comment: Aha, if i need to re engineer the application, could you please give me your advice?

Comment: In that case the business logic could written in a servlet.You could be following the MVC architecture with the presentation layer in JSP. This would be very convenient as you could leverage the power of HTML to build the interfaces.Moreover , you can seamlessly reach all required people on the internet by deploying your application on a j2ee compatible application server like Apache tomcat.